# React.memo(Component) is rendeing by parent component rendering

Tags: reactjs, optimization, memo

I have this optimization problem:

My memo child component is rerendering when I change a state in parent,

```
export default React.memo(connect(stateToProps)(React.memo(Compromisos)));
```

Currently, I am expoting him like that (I also proved to delete one of the memoization one at a time)

memo component renders by parent:

[image: React profiler img]

Thanks you a lot!